# No new version of freemat available

Tags: package-management

On 14.04 system I have:

```
freemat/trusty,now 4.0-5build1 i386 [installed]
  mathematics framework (mostly matlab compatible)

freemat-data/trusty,now 4.0-5build1 all [installed,automatic]
  freemat data files

freemat-help/trusty,now 4.0-5build1 all [installed,automatic]
  freemat help files
```

But I cannot find a newer version of the software.

Comment: What exactly is the question ? You cannot find newer version of software ?

Comment: Yes. I cannot find newer version of software.

Answer (score 1):

[Freemat 4.0-5build1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/freemat) is the newest version for 14.04.

If you need a newer version, you should probably install from source, or upgrade to [18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/freemat), which has Freemat 4.2 available.

You can show more information about a package with `apt policy packagename`. This is what is shown on 18.04:

```
$ apt policy freemat
freemat:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.2+dfsg1-6
  Version table:
     4.2+dfsg1-6 500
        500 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems that [FreeMat project](http://freemat.sourceforge.net/) has stopped its developing. The [*files* section on SourceForge site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freemat/files/) contain files not newer than 2013-08-15.

The [search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=freemat) confirms this hypotheses - modern Ubuntu 18.04 version have version 4.2.

So I think that we can compile the application 4.2 from source on your current Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system.

Follow these steps:

1. Remove your current FreeMat

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge freemat freemat-data freemat-help
   ```
2. Install all needed development tools

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential git devscripts python-all-dev llvm-dev doxygen libffi-dev libboost-math-dev libclang-dev libedit-dev xvfb
   ```
3. Install build dependencies for FreeMat

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep freemat
   ```
4. Get source of FreeMat (source code is hosted on Debian servers, it is normal)

   ```
   git clone -b debian/4.2+dfsg1-6 https://salsa.debian.org/science-team/freemat.git
   ```
5. Compile FreeMat to Debian packages

   ```
   cd freemat
   rm debian/source/format # to support compilation on 14.04
   rm -rf tests/ # remove tests
   mkdir tests/ # create empty tests directory 
   dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -d
   ```
6. Install compiled deb-packages to the system

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libjs-jquery
   sudo dpkg -i ../freemat*.deb
   ```
7. Enjoy

   [image: FreeMat 4.2 on 14.04 LTS]

Answer (score 0):

Freemat 4.2 is in 18.04 (Bionic).

No community members have volunteered to backport 4.2 to 14.04 (Trusty).